# VBA - late binding in class module - Implements statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to parse XML files and save them as CSV. I tried to remove Microsoft XML 6.0 reference and base my code only on late bindings, but I don't know how to replace `ContentHandlerImpl`. As it is now, code does not compile, because of user defined type not defined for `Implements IVBSAXContentHandler` in class module.

Can I use late binding in this case? Is there any good way to get late binding object name based on early binding name, for example `ContentHandlerImpl`? Finally there is `Set saxReader = Nothing` in the end of the code, won't `End Sub` do the job?

```
Sub main()

Dim parsePath As String
'Dim saxReader As SAXXMLReader60
Dim saxReader As Object
Dim saxhandler As ContentHandlerImpl

'Set saxReader = New SAXXMLReader60
Set saxReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader.6.0")
Set saxhandler = New ContentHandlerImpl

Set saxReader.contentHandler = saxhandler

parsePath = "file://" & Sheet7.Range("b5")

saxReader.parseURL parsePath

Set saxReader = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you want late binding in the first place? And indeed, `Set saxReader = Nothing` is superfluous.

Comment: If you implement an interface the compiler needs to understand what you are implementing, it gets information at compile time from the type lib that is exposed from the referenced library.  If you early bind that information simply does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully undestand. What interface are we talking about? What information is not available at compile-time so that early binding wouldn't work?

Comment: Woops I meant its not available with late binding. (as far as I can see OP wants to implement IVBSAXContentHandler late bound)

Comment: That's right, I will get this as an answer.